# Postgres parallel/efficient load huge amount of data psycopg

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, locking, load

I want to load many rows from a CSV file.
The file​s​ contain​ data like these​ "article​_name​,​article_time,​start_time,​end_time"

There is a contraint on the table: for the same article name, i don't insert a new row if the new ​article_time falls in an existing range​ [start_time,​end_time]​ for the same article.
ie: don't insert row y if exists [​start_time_x,​end_time_x] for which time_article_y inside range  [​start_time_x,​end_time_x]  , with article_​name_​y = article_​name_​x

- I tried ​with psycopg by selecting the existing article names ad checking manually if there is an overlap --> too long
- I tried again with psycopg, this time by setting a condition 'exclude using...' and tryig to insert with specifying "on conflict do nothing" (so that it does not fail) but still too long
- I tried the same thing but this time trying to insert many values at each call of execute (psycopg): it got a little better (1M rows processed in almost 10minutes)​, but still not as fast as it needs to be for the amount of data ​I have (500M+)
- I tried to parallelize by calling the same script many time, on different files but the timing didn't get any better, I guess because of the locks on the table each time we want to write something

Is there any way to create a lock only on rows containing the same article_name? (and not a lock on the whole table?)
Could you please help with any idea to make this parallellizable and/or more time efficient?

​Lots of thanks folks​

Comment: I'd load the whole csv first then the insert .. select .. overlap. copy to table without indexes will be fastest possible. isolation control on query instead of copying csv is as flexible as possible...

Comment: Thanks Vao but the same problem will be there. Loading the data from csv is really quick. But then transferring to a table with checking the condition is really long. It should be parallelizable somehow but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with the exclusion constraint and `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` is good.

You could improve the speed as follows:

- Do it all in a single transaction.
- Like Vao Tsun suggested, maybe `COPY` the data into a staging table first and do it all with a single SQL statement.
- Remove all indexes except the exclusion constraint from the table where you modify data and re-create them when you are done.
- Speed up insertion by disabling autovacuum and raising `max_wal_size` (or `checkpoint_segments` on older PostgreSQL versions) while you load the data.

Comment: This way, there is no parallel operation right? This can be ok for 1M rows, but definitely time consuming for 100s of millions.

Comment: I don't know if parallelization can buy you a lot, and your experiments seem to suggest that the gain is rather limited. I couldn't think of a better way than running several `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` statements in parallel (that handle different input data). I guess the limiting factor is the relative complexity of your condition.